# How do you globally add directives from an external file to Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, directive

If you are trying to add directives to a Vue 3 app how do you add them so they are globally available without having to add them to each component?

Comment: Are you answering your own question *within* your question? If so, best to separate the two, keeping the question text within the question and the answer text within a separate and distinct answer. See: [Can you answer your own questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Not your down-voter (yet), but again, please answer my comment when/if you can.

Comment: your wish is my command. fixed to make the masses happy.

Answer (score 5):

Create a directives file called /src/directives/directives.js. I have placed my file into a directives folder to keep it clean.

```
// focus text input on mounted
const focus = {mounted: (el) => el.focus()}
export { focus }
```

In the main.js file import your directive and globally register it to your app.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { focus } from "./directives/directives.js"

const app = createApp(App)
app.directive("focus", focus)
.mount('#app')
```

Finally, in your component use the directive.

`<input type="text" v-focus>`

Answer (score 2):

```
Simply rename the variable name to vFocus !
```

Here another example with Vue + Typescipt

create a directive file eg. 'HelloDirective.ts'

```
export const vSayHello = { mounted: (el: Element) => (el.innerHTML = 'hello') }
```

import into your component with

```
import { vSayHello } from '@/directives/HelloDirective'
```

add directive into your html template

```
<span v-say-hello>old text</span>
```